# Electron app: How do you use ipcRenderer.sendToHost()?

Tags: webview, ipc, electron

In the Electron [documentation for the webview tag](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-view-tag/#event-ipc-message), the following example is given to show how to communicate between the renderer process and the web page hosted in the webview:

> With sendToHost method and ipc-message event you can easily communicate between guest page and embedder page:
>
> ```
> // In embedder page.
> const webview = document.getElementById('foo')
> webview.addEventListener('ipc-message', (event) => {
>   console.log(event.channel)
>   // Prints "pong"
> })
> webview.send('ping')
>
> // In guest page.
> const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
> ipcRenderer.on('ping', () => {
>   ipcRenderer.sendToHost('pong')
> })
> ```

However, in my guest web page (inside the webview), I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when I try to `require('electron')`, as indicated in the docs.

Is there something else I need to do to be able to require the ipcRenderer module from the guest web page?

**Electron version:** 1.4.6

**Note:** I'm not sure if this is important or not, but the page running inside my webview is served from a local server. In my top-level page in the renderer process, I do something like: `document.getElementById("webview").src = "http://localhost:1234/...";`.

**Edit:** It looks like serving my web page from a local server does not change anything. I have the same error after trying with a static HTML file. It looks like the example in the docs simply doesn't work, or I'm understanding it wrong.

```
// Simple foo.html somewhere on my computer
<script>
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
        ipcRenderer.on('ping', () => {
        ipcRenderer.sendToHost('pong')
    })
</script>

// In embedder page, in renderer process
document.getElementById("webview").src = "file://path/to/foo.html";
```

Output from the embedded page (inside the webview):
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

For security reasons, the preferred way to use `require` in renderer processes is to use `preload` to inject only the minimum node integration your page requires. See point 2) of [Electron's security recommendations](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#disable-node.js-integration-for-remote-content). A minimal example for `ipcRenderer`:

```
// main.ts
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
    preload: './preload.js'
  }
})

mainWindow.loadURL('https://my-website.com')
```

```
// preload.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

window.sendToElectron= function (channel) {
  ipcRenderer.send(channel)
}
```

In your webpage you can now use `window.sendToElectron("ping")`.

If you're using `<webview>` inside the renderer process, you can use `<webview src="page.html" preload="./preload.js" />` to achieve the same result. So, that's what I would use to answer my original question, and inside `preload.js` I would inject a function that calls `ipcRenderer.sendToHost("pong")` in the global `window`.

---

### Old answer (bad for security)

I had missed a vital point in the webview docs. To be able to call `require` from the page embedded inside the webview, you need to set the `nodeintegration` attribute on the webview tag:

`<webview id="webview" nodeintegration />`

Comment: It should be noted here that nodeIntegration for webviews is very, very dangerous. Ask yourself if you really need it. If the webview is used to render external / 3rd party content don't do it!

Comment: Yes, answer was quite old. I edited it to reflect best practices.

Comment: This isn't bad for security if it's your own code running in the webview.